# Python / Django - Class Dictionary Persistent in View?

Tags: python, django

I have a class in Django that is stored in the utils directory.  I use this class almost like a model for my views.py.  I am experiencing the weirdest behavior.  I instantiate the class and have a dictionary belonging to it; however, the dictionary seems to be saved / cached / remembered on the next page load.

```
class my_class:
    id = {"section": None, "sub_section": None, "topic": None, "page": None}

    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request
        return True

    def set_ids(self):
        self.id['section'] = 1
        self.id['sub_section'] = 1
        self.id['topic'] = 1
        self.id['page'] = 1
```

This sample class is being instantiated in my views.py file:

```
@login_required
def example(self):
    object = my_class(request)
    print object.id
    object.set_ids()
```

For some crazy reason the printed object id's are persistent.  That being, next page load, before id's are set with the class method "set_ids", the id's from the previous page load are still existent...???....   STUMPED!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field `my_class.id` is a *class* field not an *instance member*, so there is only one copy of `my_class.id` for every `my_class` instance.

If you want `id` to be unique for every instance, you need to initialize it in `__init__`:

```
def __init(self, request):
    ...
    self.id = { ... }
```

Comment: Ahhhhhh.  That makes perfect sense.  I'm used to coding PHP :) .  Thanks!